# "Object of class could not be converted to int" yii cdetailview

Tags: php, yii

What I want to do is relating the **clist** and **findByPk**, to get consument_name from fk.consument_id on table 1

and this is the relation between MasterTransaction and Consument

> table1(MasterTransaction)
>   1.transaction_id
>   2.consument_id
>
> table2(Consument)
>   1.consument_id
>   2.consument_name

```
<h1>View MasterTransaction #<?php echo $model->kode_transaksi; ?></h1>

<?echo $consument_id=intval($model->consument_id);?>

<? $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
        'transaction_id',
  array('name'=>'consument_id','value'=>intval(Consument::model()>findByPK($consument_id))),    
        '
    ),
));
```

and this warning came to my browser :

> “Object of class Konsumen could not be converted to int”

I need help from you guys, to get the name from fk_id.

Comment: You should write your code in english. If someone has to work on it which does not comprehend your language - which is right now the case - you're giving them a harder time than necessary.

Comment: you are converting object to integer in `intval(Consument::model()>findByPK($consument_id))`

Comment: okay  , i did the english few minutes ago :)

Comment: ohh, so it can't be converted to integer at all ??, please help me to show the consument_name with fk.consument_id on CDetailview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're looking for consument_name? Try this:

```
<? $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
        'transaction_id',
  array('name'=>'consument_id','value'=>Consument::model()>findByPK($consument_id)->consument_name),    
     ),
 ));
```

But you'd be better of declaring a 'consument' relation in your MasterTransaction Model so you can do this:

```
<? $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
    'data'=>$model,
    'attributes'=>array(
        'transaction_id',
  array('name'=>'consument_id','value'=>$model->consument->consument_name),    
     ),
 ));
```

Comment: yes im looking for that field, but can't do about set the relation on MasterTransaction model, because i still didn't get it, so i was using findByPk so far for relation

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are expecting primary key value from `Consument` model.

Then change below line

```
Consument::model()>findByPK($consument_id)
```

to

```
Consument::model()>findByPK($consument_id)->getPrimaryKey();
```

So you will get primary key field value if record found. Otherwise 0 will be returned.

Comment: You're searching a record by Primary Key, which is `$consument_id` and then try to get PRIMARY KEY??? Isn't it `$consument_id` itself?

Comment: yes, it did show the primary key value, but i still hope it could show the value of the consument_name from a foreign key on table 1 :)

Comment: then can you tell me the relation name? or did you try @jbg solution?

Comment: no, i didn't set the relations on MasterTransaction model, i really have a difficulties on that